# How to set up SQL Server online with public Wi-Fi

Tags: sql-server, configuration, network, tcpip

I am doing a school project where I have to set up a SQL Server database for my teammates to work on. Currently, I am able to host the server online with my home router, but I am facing problems bringing the database server to school, where the Wi-Fi does not allows me to do port forwarding.

I only have one laptop and the database server needs to be available online while connected to the school's secured Wi-Fi.

Hence, what would be the best way to host the database server in school? (using SQL Server) Secureness of the database is not an issue.

**Additional information**:

- SQL Server is on my laptop, I cant seem to find the DNS server address to set the IP configuration? (Not shown in cmd)
- There is only connection specific DNS suffix, link local ipv6, ipv4 address, subnet mask, default gateway, and connection specific DNS suffix, ipv6 address, link local ipv6 address, default gateway.
- I can connect to my own server but no one else can connect to it as I cannot establish an internet connection without a DNS server IP dynamically given by my school Wi-Fi
- We use another computer with the same iPv4 properties (IP address) on the same Wi-Fi and the same server name on SQL Server and this issue came up:

  > named pipes provider: error 40, could not open connection to server

Comment: If your laptop is at school, and you're connected to the Wi-Fi, you just need the IP address of the laptop (and the appropriate port 1433 open on the laptop firewall) in order to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: My sql server is on my laptop, I cant seem to find the dns server address to set the ip configuration? (Not shown in cmd)

Comment: Type `ipconfig` on the command line to get your IP address

Comment: There is only connection specific dns suffix, link local ipv6, ipv4 address, subnet mask, default gateway, and connection specific dns suffix, ipv6 address, link local ipv6 address, default gateway

Comment: Yeah, you’re looking for IPv4. That’s the address your laptop got when it connected to the Wi-Fi.

Comment: Ok, they also ask to use the following dns address, preferred dns server and alternate dns server

Comment: I mean I can connect to my own server but no one else can connect to it as I cannot establish an internet connection without a dns server ip dynamically given by my school wifi

Comment: If your teammates use your IP address, they can connect without DNS.

Comment: Is using Azure an option? Microsoft give you $100 in free credits https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftimagine/2018/03/01/announcing-azure-for-students/

Comment: We use another computer with the same iPv4 properties (ip address) on the same wifi and the same server name on sql server and this issue came up (named pipes provider: error 40, could not open connection to server)

Comment: After you connect to the Wi-Fi and get an IPV4 address, restart SQL Server service on your laptop so that it listens on the w-fi interface IP address. Clients on the same LAN as the Wi-Fi will be able to connect using that address as long as it's reachable via routing.